# Proving that $M$ is finitely generated from exact sequence $ 0 \to M' \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} M'' \to 0 $

Tags: ring-theory, proof-explanation, modules, exact-sequence

I'm having some trouble understanding the following proof:

---

We shall only use the assumption that $$ 0 \to M' \xrightarrow{f} M \xrightarrow{g} M'' \to 0 $$  is exact and $M''$ is finitely generated.
We see that if $x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n$ are generators for $M''$, then $\bar x_1,\bar x_2, . . . , \bar x_n$ in $\text{coker}(g) = M''/f(M')$ **[1]** will generate
$\text{coker}(g)$. But by the exactness of the sequence, $\text{coker}(g) \simeq M$ **[2]**, hence $M$ will be finitely generated.

---

My questions are:

1. In my algebra class, I remember my teacher saying that if $g: A\to B$ is a homomorphism, then the cokernel of $g$ is defined as the quotient $B/g(A)$. In this case, $g$ is surjective as the sequence of homomorphism is exact, so shouldn't we have that $\text{coker}(g)\simeq (0)$? And why did he write $\text{coker}(g)=M''/f(M')$ instead of $\text{coker}(g)=M''/g(M)$?
2. Why don't get why being exact would imply that $\text{coker}(g)\simeq M$. If I'm correct in my previous note, that would imply that $M\simeq 0$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions are valid objections and the proof makes no sense.

Also, the statement in question is false. Let $M'=M$, be any module that is not f.g. and let $M''=0$ and consider the sequence $0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$, which is just $0 \to M \to M \to 0 \to 0$. Clearly $M''$ is finitely generated, but $M$ is not.

A related, but correct statement is that $M$ is finitely generated if both $M'$ and $M''$ are finitely generated. Another related true statement is that $M''$ is finitely generated if $M$ is.

Comment: Thank you. This proof was supposed to prove that if $M',M''$ is f.g. then $M$ is f.g as you said. Do you think that the proof this can be adapted using the fact that $M'$ is also f.g?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães I don't think you can adapt it, but the proof of that is not too difficult: just take any finite generating set of $M'$, push it to $M$ via $f$ and take lifts of a finite generating set of $M''$ along $g$. Then use the exactness to prove that the union of these two generate $M$. This is the standard proof for this fact. I don't see how the proof that you cited can be adapted into this, though.

Comment: I think I get it. Just one more question if I may: What do you mean by " take lifts of ..."?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães I mean for any element in the generating set of $M''$ that you chose, take a preimage for the map $g$

Comment: thank you, now I get it. Ill give that a try